# Wait for "return value" from Javascript modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

OK, I'm by no means a JavaScript guru, and perhaps I'm still thinking in terms of Desktop software development, but this is what I'm trying to achieve :

- I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap's Modals](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)
- In some cases, before an action takes place, I want to verify it with a "Are you sure?" (Yes/No) Modal Dialog.

**Question :**

- What should the inner logic be?

**I mean :**

- User clicks buttonA (which ultimately performs actionA)
- I want to launch the modal, wait for the input (either of the 2 buttons - yes/no) and/or pass it to some checking routine before performing(or not) actionA

This my HTML code for the modal (should the buttons be - somehow - acting via their `onclick` javascript routines?) - also note that `#confirmMessage` is going to be variable.

```
<div class="modal fade hide" id="confirmAlert">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
        <h3 id="confirmTitle">Are you sure?</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="confirmMessage">Body</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Yes</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Just an idea:**

- Write a function like `checkBeforeExec(message,functionToExec)`
- Set `#confirmMessage` to message and Yes' href to `javascript:functionToExec`
- Makes sense?

---

I know it may sound a bit confusing - but I simply do not know what the most javascript-friendly way to do this would be...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I created a dialog manager around modal, with `confirm` helper function that does essentially this:

```
var callback = function(result) {
  alert(result);
}); // define your callback somewhere

$('#confirmAlert').on('click', '.btn, .close', function() {
  $(this).addClass('modal-result'); // mark which button was clicked
}).on('hidden', function() {
  var result = $(this).find('.modal-result').filter('.btn-danger').length > 0; // attempt to filter by what you consider the "YES" button; if it was clicked, result should be true.

  callback(result); // invoke the callback with result
});
```

Also, you should make both the Cancel and Yes button `data-dismiss="modal"`.

[Here's a fiddle, with a simple example of my dialog manager](http://jsfiddle.net/p8LuT/1/).

Note, that if you are using *Bootstrap 3*, you should add a handler to the `hidden.bs.modal` event instead of `hidden`.

Comment: `you should make both the Cancel and Yes button` - This might not work if you stop event propagation in event handler. In that case, use `modal('hide')` on clicking yes.

Answer (score 1):

With jquery you can use something like

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
   val=$(this).val()
   if(val=='Yes'){
     //continue the processing
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very late now but we have a library that can achieve the results. https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Sweetalert will perform those actions with ease.